# Как можно ограничить количество распределённо запускаемых экземпляров приложения?

Tags: java, android

Нужно каким-нибудь образом сделать так, чтобы собственное приложение запускалось только на 50 машинах, и не более. Чтобы при большем количестве подключени не получалось.

Как это реализовать? Есть сервер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое поднять на сервере пул idшников и при запуске приложения просить у сервера один из них. Если сервер не дает idшник то приложение не запускается, иначе запускается.

Comment: можно поподробнее пожалуйста ( мне нужно чтоб работало именно 50 машин

Comment: Пусть на каждом клиенте будет кнопка логина, по нажатию делается запрос к серверу который либо отдает idшник из свободных либо и помечает его как заданный, либо говорит что все idшники заняты и клиент не логинится. Собственно количество idшников будет равно максимальному количеству работающих клиентов. Так же надо сделать освобожение idшника, например по закрытию приложения.

Comment: как раелизовать занятый айдишник? типа он занят и больше нельзя.

Comment: Можно использовать boolean массив на 50 элементов, если id из массива занят то по его индексу храниться false если свободен то true.

Comment: поддерживать актуальность данных в таком хранилище не так легко, как кажется на первый взгляд

Comment: как предложите в итоге попробовать? может какието свои наработки есть?

Comment: Вся сложность в том как определять когда idшник можно считать свободным. Так что зависит от конкретной задачи.